# How does a tablet automatically power on when a power source is connected?

Tags: boot, automation

Please imagine a car situation where you have an Android tablet:

http://content.worldcarfans.co/2014/11/24/thumbnails/24486128385597.hl2.jpg

And the following working rules (as expected in most cases):

- If the car is *OFF*, tablet is *OFF*;
- If the car is *ON*, tablet is *ON* (automatically);

I have been reading about enabling *auto power on mode* when the charger is connected: most tablets have the `playlpm`, `lpm`, or a specific file that displays the battery charging animation.
The trick is to **overwrite** these files and **force** a boot.

Furthermore, I have also checked and tested [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en), where I was able to achieve this behavior only when USB is connected.

However, I would like to know if there's anyway we can do it if the tablet **has no battery attached on it**.

Would this same approach work?

Comment: I'm aware of phones (Chinese mainly) that doesn't power on (connected to power source) unless battery is plugged in. They don't show any animation, LED blink or any vibration at all in such state; that doesn't mean they don't detect the source since I flashed one of them in such state. IDK maybe firmware has something to do here. Can't say about tablets though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this situation only by **removing** the battery.

Turns out that most tablet's **automatically power on** when they're directly connected to an **external** power source.

Answer (score -2):

Solved simply by removing battery and shorting power button on lenovo a2020